# Difference between Vim's "job_start()" function and Neovim's "jobstart()" function?

Tags: vim, lua, neovim

I found an ancient Vim plug-in that looks to be useful to me: https://github.com/rolf007/multiplayer.vim.

Unfortunately, I was getting errors thrown by the `job_start` function used in a couple of the places. Apparently, that function does not exist. Since I use Neovim, I replaced `job_start` in the module with `jobstart`. Miraculously, it seemed to fix the error.

But I have no idea if `jobstart` is a drop in replacement. Seems odd that it would be given the Neovim strives to be a drop-in replacement for Vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, Neovim doesn't strive to be a drop-in replacement for Vim at all. Compatibility with Vim has never been a goal of the project.

   Moreover, Neovim's "job" feature came *before* Vim's so there is really no reason whatsoever to expect the two to be compatible in any way.
2. As a quick look at their respective documentation would have told you, Neovim's `:help jobstart()` and Vim's `:help job_start()` have similar signatures but accept different options, which makes them mutually incompatible.

   The plugin in question appears to be calling `job_start()` two times:

   - [One without options](https://github.com/rolf007/multiplayer.vim/blob/master/autoload/multiplayer.vim#L48), which can be replaced with Neovim's `jobstart()` without side-effects,
   - [One with options](https://github.com/rolf007/multiplayer.vim/blob/master/autoload/multiplayer.vim#L50), which *might* be replaced with a straight `jobstart()` but you *might* have problems with the options. If the implementation of `jobstart()` is not very strict, then it will ignore the unknown option, if it is strict, then it will throw an error.

     That said, Neovim's `:help on_stdout` seems to be equivalent to Vim's `:help out_cb` in spirit, so changing the name of the option might be enough, **if the way the callback function is implemented allows it**.

     That callback function would be the ideal place for something to break.

   Note that it also calls `:help job_stop()`, which you will have to deal with as well so, no, simply doing `:%s/job_start/jobstart` won't be enough to port that plugin to Neovim.